# Simple material (diffuse nodes mixed through a "Pointiness" factor) does not work in EEVEE

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, node-editor, eevee-render-engine

I have a material that works very well in Cycles, but nothing appears in EEVEE. Where does this problem come from? Is there any way to fix that?

[image]

Comment: Relevant: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/88764/do-nodes-in-eevee-work-the-same-as-in-cycles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not all shader nodes that work with Cycles work also with Eevee. The Geometry "Pointiness" socket doesn't, as well as the other "geometry-aware" nodes like Ambient Occlusion or Bevel.

Here is a reference about node support: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/eevee/materials/nodes_support.html

If your mesh isn't animated, you can bake Pointiness using Cycles and then use it in Eevee:

1. Unwrap your mesh,
2. connect the end of the Color Ramp to an Emission shader and the Emission Shader to the Material Output
3. Add an Image Texture<sup>*</sup> node, with a blank, new image, and leave it unconnected, but selected
4. Bake in "Emission" mode (while using Cycles)
5. Save the baked image
6. Use the baked image as a Texture<sup>*</sup> for the Mix factor in Eevee

<sup>* if you have multiple UV maps, the image textures must always have their Vector input connected to the correct UV Map node.</sup>